# how can this html code be modified to allow a user to input the number of format rows present on a webpage?

Tags: javascript

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  num: <input type="number" name="a" id="num"><br>
 <button onclick="addnewrow()">Add</button>
</form>
```

```js
function addnewrow(num) {
  var num   = document.getElementById('num').value
  var count = 1

  for (i = 0; i <=num; i++)
    {
    var newrow = '<div class="row">'
               + '<div class="col-md-4">'
               + '<div class="form-group label-floating">'
               + '<label class="control-label">Title + count</label>'
               + '<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="act" >'
               + '</div>'
               + '</div>'
               + '</div>';
    count++:
    return newrow;
    }
}
```

This html code is supposed to take in an input number in the first form the output that number of form rows, however this doesn't work how can this be amended for it to work

Comment: `return` always exits a function, the loop will only run once. Also, what are you doing with the return value?

Comment: change to -> `.... l">Title' + count + '</label>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I am selecting button using `document.querySelector("#add")`.
- After that I am attaching `click` event on it.
- `e.preventDefault()` to stop default behavior of form for submitting.
- Than I am taking number value converting it to integer from string input and running `for-loop`.
- I am not validating user input here.
- And lastly, appending row in selected `main` div using `innerHTML`.

```js
const main = document.querySelector("#main");

const addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
addButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value);
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    main.innerHTML += `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group label-floating"><label class="control-label">Title + count</label><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="act"></div></div></div>`
  }
});
```

```css
'<div class="row">'+'<div class="col-md-4">'+'<div class="form-group label-floating">'+'<label class="control-label">Title + count</label>'+'<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="act" >'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>';
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  num: <input type="number" name="a" id="num"><br>
  <button id="add">Add</button>
  <div id="main"></div>
</form>
```